# Remoting Connection Exception - Connect to server failed

Tags: rocketmq

I setup RocketMQ (4.1.0-incubating-release) on *macOS Sierra (10.12.3)* and started it's nameserver and broker as per [this instruction](https://rocketmq.apache.org/docs/quick-start/). Nameserver and broker start up well. However I can't create a new topic or see topic list or see a status of any topic. I get the following error.

```
$ sh bin/mqadmin updateTopic -n localhost:9876 -c DefaultCluster -r 2 -w 2 -t MY_TOPIC

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=128m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=128m; support was removed in 8.0

org.apache.rocketmq.remoting.exception.RemotingConnectException: connect to **<[fe80:-2>** failed
    at org.apache.rocketmoi.remoting.netty.NettyRemotingClient.invokeSync(NettyRemotingClient.java:357)
    at org.apache.rocketmq.client.impl.MQClientAPIImpl.createTopic(MQClientAPIImpl.java:266)
    at org.apache.rocketmq.tools.admin.DefaultMQAdminExtImpl.createAndUpdateTopicConfig(DefaultMQAdminExtImpl.java:176)
    at org.apache.rocketmq.tools.admin.DefaultMQAdminExt.createAndUpdateTopicConfig(DefaultMQAdminExt.java:156)
    at org.apache.rocketmq.tools.command.topic.UpdateTopicSubCommand.execute(UpdateTopicSubCommand.java:154)
    at org.apache.rocketmq.tools.command.MQAdminStartup.mainO(MQAdminStartup.java:128)
    at org.apache.rocketmq.tools.command.MQAdminStartup.main(MQAdminStartup.java:78)
```

I tried both compiling the source myself and downloaded the compiled binary from Apache's site. I also tried *4.0.0-incubating-release* binary. It allowed to me to list the topics using `sh mqadmin topicList`. But it didn't allow me to create a new topic owing to the above exception.

I don't see any relevant log in any of the rocketmq logs (namesrv.log, broker.log or remoting.log).

I wonder if it's a bug or some problem with my setup.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following two lines to the configuration file (*broker.conf*) solved the issue.

```
brokerIP1=localhost
brokerIP2=localhost
```